# How to fix error that is generated when custom splash screen is launched?

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

When making a splash screen in flutter an error comes up, this is it:

```
Could not update files on device: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:59086/vscyX6-w-Zo=/
```

The screen is loaded but doesn't show anything after the screen. I have not programmed a custom screen. I edited the launch_background file and all the mipmap files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to this is because the image file was to big to fit on the screen so it should be modified to scale. also because the right emulator and sdk should be used